# Using cookies websites showing items on different website

Tags: asp.net, .net, cookies

Once I visit a ecommerce website and then go to some other website, I see the items that I visited on the 1st ecommerce website. I want this technique to be implemented on my website too. What is this technique called and how can I implement this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poor man single sign on ? The basic technique is quite simple - you have one root cookie domain like 'www.cookie.com'; and cookie like "ID" on that domain.

On your ecommerce page, include javascript, that will check if cookie "LocalID" exists in page; if it doesn't add reference to

```
<script src="www.cookie.com"></script>
```

This script will be served by .ashx handler on www.cookie.com domain; with behavior:

1) if no cookie value for "ID" exists, create new "ID" cookie and assign it random guid

2) send back script

3) this script will set cookie "LocalID" to have the same value as the "ID" cookie (handler on www.cookie.com will generate javascript dynamically)

That's pretty much it, you can now relay on LocalID cookie to be unique for the same user (more precisely browser with cookies turned on) across different websites on every ecommerce domain implementing this. Now you just need some persistent storage to which your applications have access to (webservice, database) and use LocalID cookie as key for retrieving/persisting user profile.